# Tell a class on creation the type of a member variable

Tags: java, oop

Suppose I have a `CityDistrict` class as follows:

```
class CityDistrict {
    List<House> houses;
    ...
}
```

Suppose for some usecases an `ArrayList` would be the better fit for `houses` and sometimes an `LinkedList` for example. How would you tell the CityDistrict on creation what class it should use for `houses`

My three ideas are:

1) Is this a usecase for parametric classes? Something like

```
class CityDistrict<T> {
    T<House> houses;
    ...
}
```

Then you could create a `CityDistrict<ArrayList>`. But I suppose the information that T should be of the type `List` is lost here.

2) Or you could create several Constructors or static factory methods like `generateArrayListCityDistrict` but this is kind of ugly I think.

3) Use some kind of flag variable in the constructor `CityDistrict(int ListFlag)` and map `1` to `ArrayList` and so forth. Also kind of ugly I think.

Am I missing the obvious here? What would be a clean and OOP way of handling this situation?

Comment: Of how many different classes (`LinkedList`, `ArrayList` etc.) are we talking?

Comment: For a start: two. But I don't know if this changes in the future.

Comment: Use a factory to obtain the instance of `List` needed?

Comment: Does whatever is creating the instance have the context?  If yes, perhaps pass in the concrete `List` in the constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could pass a `Supplier<List<House>>` to a constructor. It is going to decide what implementation the instance should use:

```
class CityDistrict {

    List<House> houses;

    public CityDistrict(Supplier<List<House>> implementation) {
        houses = implementation.get();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CityDistrict arrayListImpl = new CityDistrict(ArrayList::new);
        CityDistrict linkedListImpl = new CityDistrict(LinkedList::new);
    }

}
```

Though, I am not pretty sure if it is OK when your API user can decide what the implementation should be used internally (especially if it can affect some performance issues). That breaks the rules of encapsulation a bit. And it is important if you care about OOP techniques (what you normally should do).

I would rather provide the default implementation (the `ArrayList` is a good choice here) and add the ability to switch to a desired implementation by a factory method:

```
class CityDistrict {

    List<House> houses;

    private CityDistrict(Supplier<List<House>> supplier) {
        houses = supplier.get();
    }

    public CityDistrict() {
        this(ArrayList::new);
    }

    public CityDistrict with(Supplier<List<House>> implementation) {
        return new CityDistrict(implementation);
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem around encapsulation comes from the fact that `Supplier<List>` is an open-ended thing, it can return literally anything that implements `List`. To test your class against every possible implementation is obviously impossible, so you either test for a few and say "there are no guarantees for anything else", or you can use an enum that contains all the valid "modes" of your class, with each value of the enum representing a different `List` implementation. Depending on the actual use case, both solutions can be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @biziclop: you rarely test an application against every possible scenario as that’s usually impossible. You may design the class in a way that it works correctly when the `List` fulfills the contract, usually tested against some implementations which max out the corner cases, but, of course, you can’t make performance guaranties for arbitrary implementations, but if performance is you concern, you’ll end up always using `ArrayList` for the single threaded case anyway…

Comment: @Holger That is true, but what I wanted to say is "don't open your class any more than it is necessary for it to perform its task". So if you're writing `Collections.sort()`, sure you have to keep it open to all `List` implementations. But if your code only ever has to work with `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, don't open it up to any other, and then you can test it fully with the two implementations that you do support.